# creating a virtual server in virtualmin ( unable to complete installation)

Tags: mysql, linux, virtualmin

I'm trying to create a virtual server in virtualmin and getting a MYSQL error . Though MYSQl is perfectly installed.

The error is :

> Creating MySQL login ..
>   .. MySQL database failed! : SQL insert into user (host, user, ssl_type, ssl_cipher, x509_issuer, x509_subject, plugin, authentication_string) values ('localhost', 'websiteoptimizer', '', '', '', '', 'mysql_native_password', password('heY7pmqgucBgwyPj')) failed : Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements at /usr/libexec/webmin/web-lib-funcs.pl line 1427.

What should i do now ??

Answer (score 0):

The error is reasonably clear, isn't it? Your password doesn't satisfy the password policy you've configured. I don't know what policy you've implemented, but changing the password to satisfy it should resolve the error.